# "clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn" error in macro

Tags: clojure, macros

Here is the code:

```
(defmacro cond2 [& body]
  (when body
    `(if ~(first body)
       ~(if (next body)
          (second body)
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "error")))
       ~(cond2 (next (next (body)))))))
(cond2 (> 2 1) (println "2 > 1")
       :else   (println "2 <= 1"))
```

I got this error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn, compiling:(/Users/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/cina/src/cina/ref_types.clj:1:24)
```

If I remove the recursive part, the error goes away:

```
(defmacro cond2 [& body]
  (when body
    `(if ~(first body)
       ~(if (next body)
          (second body)
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "error")))
       )))
```

this only works for a body with two clauses, of course.

If I quote the recursive part like this:

```
(defmacro cond2 [& body]
  (when body
    `(if ~(first body)
       ~(if (next body)
          (second body)
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "error")))
       `(cond2 ~(next (next body))))))
```

then I get a different error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: cina.ref-types/body, compiling:(/Users/personal_config_bin_files/workspace/cina/src/cina/ref_types.clj:331:5)
```

Using `cons` instead of syntax-quote works:

```
(defmacro cond2 [& body]
  (when body
    `(if ~(first body)
       ~(if (next body)
          (second body)
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "error")))
       ~(cons 'cond2 (next (next body))))))
(cond2 (> 2 3) (println "good")
       :else   (println "bad"))
```

But I don't know what the difference is. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

It's unquote-splice that I need here:

```
(defmacro cond2 [& body]
  (when body
    `(if ~(first body)
       ~(if (next body)
          (second body)
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "error")))
       (cond2 ~@(next (next body))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `(body)` in your original recursive part - it tries to call `body` as a function, and then complains that it cannot cast the seq to a function.

Do `(next (next body))` instead, and it should work fine.

Comment: Well, it solves the problem causing your error message. But as you are pointing out yourself, you also need to "unwrap" your argument list (or use `apply`). `cons` takes the "first" and "next" pieces of a list, and therefore does this for you implicitly.